# NPM: Unexpected identifier

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

I’m working on a small project with Laravel and VueJS, but I’m having some trouble with npm, when I want to run „npm run watch“ to test changes on a vue component. I’m running it all on Mac OS 10.14.6.

My node version is v6.11.2 and my npm version is 6.14.4.

This is the error I’m receiving:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:151
  async remove(item) {
        ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
    at Module._compile (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:186:36)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:98:17)
    at Module._compile (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at implementation (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Sass.js:55:27)
    at implementation (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:130:61)
    at global.tap (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/helpers.js:10:5)
    at Sass.loaderOptions (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:128:9)
    at extractPlugin (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:87:39)
    at global.tap (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/helpers.js:10:5)
    at details.forEach (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:27:13)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Sass.webpackRules (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:22:22)
    at ComponentFactory.applyRules (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:155:23)
    at Mix.listen.rules (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:66:48)
    at events.(anonymous function).forEach.handler (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:34:47)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Dispatcher.fire (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:34:28)
    at Mix.dispatch (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:118:25)
    at WebpackConfig.buildRules (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:90:13)
    at WebpackConfig.build (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:23:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:29:38)
    at Module._compile (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novellum/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Any suggestions what to do? I already deleted my node_modules folder, my package-lock.json and created it all new, uninstalled npm and reinstalled it via brew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happening because your version of NodeJS don't support async/await calls. You must update your NodeJS to minimum 7.6, but I suggest using v12.x.x.

Check https://nodejs.org/en/ on how to download it and update on your operating system.

Comment: That's the solution. I tried that already via brew, but that didn't work. With the package from the occial NodeJS site, everything is fine. Thanks!